# running/ compiling system verilog snippets(not an entire set of testbench verification codes) on windows

Tags: powershell, system-verilog

I am trying to compile and run small snippets of systemverilog on windows. I am trying to do that in powershell. Is there any way, I can do that ?

Comment: Probably, yes. What have you tried and what happened?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  You may find http://www.edaplayground.com easier for small and contained snippets of code.

Comment: I entered qverilog followed by the sv filename while being in the same folder as that of the file. It seemed to initialise questa sim at first but later it ended without doing or showing anything. Basically I am used to working on linux and there I used to watch the code being compiled and ran without opening any tool, and the output was visible in the shell prompt itself. I am trying to achieve the same thing only in windows using powershell/commandprompt